# Stop To Getting Email Copy that are sent from my server

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I have a website lets say "www.abc.com" and hosted on cpanel.
There is an email id of admin for this domain, lets say "admin@abc.com".
Now I have created a web-service for an iOS application i.e. for registration. In this web-service, a email has been sent to registered user that he has successfully registered in system.

Suppose I am registering in system with email "test@abc.com" then an email sent to "test@abc.com" successfully. But when this email is sent to user, admin (admin@abc.com) also get a copy of this email.

Note :: I am using PHP mailer library for sending email.

My Code for sending email ::

```
$from = 'XXXX@gmail.com';
//$message = "test msg.";
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'error_log';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 465;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = $from;

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "XXXXXX";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($from, 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($from, 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($to, 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML($email_header.$message.$email_footer);
```

This way suppose 100 users are registered in my system then then admin will get 100 email.
I don't why its happening.

I want to stop to sent email copy to admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include relevant code showing your system emailing with the mailer library? I'm sure there's code that is doing that, either that or the settings on your mail server are also emailing a copy of each mail.

Comment: I have added my code